# stack vertically divs when using float

Tags: html, css

I am trying to stack divs vertically using float: left.

But they stack horizontally by default.

Any solution using css?

This is what **i want** to get:

```
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  1  |  6  |  11 |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  2  |  7  |  12 |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  3  |  8  |  13 |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  4  |  9  |  14 |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  5  |  10 |  15 |
> +-----+-----+-----+
```

This is what i get:

```
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  1  |  2  |  3  |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  4  |  5  |  6  |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  7  |  8  |  9  |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  10 |  11 |  12 |
> +-----+-----+-----+
> |  13 |  14 |  15 |
> +-----+-----+-----+
```

An image of the div that I want to rearrange: 
[image: An image of the items that I want to rearrange]

Each div contains a number, an image and a name.
this is the code for the div:

```
#championsWrapper {
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
}
```

Comment: why arent you using tables for that? any specific reason?

Comment: Arrange your divs in columns : ))

Comment: Look into column overflow and its counterparts, https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

Comment: Using tables the contents still displays in the wrong order

Comment: Cant arrange the divs in columns because its a dynamic content :( the columns should be changed constantly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using CSS columns, using `column-count` (and the various vendor-prefixes for this property):

```css
#container {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -ms-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
}
#container div {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
  <div class="item">19</div>
  <div class="item">20</div>
  <div class="item">21</div>
</div>
```

If required you can use the `column-rule` property to add vertical lines to visually separate the columns, using the same syntax as the `border` property (`column-rule-width` `column-rule-style` `column-rule-color`):

```css
#container {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -ms-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-rule: 2px solid #999;
  -ms-column-rule: 2px solid #999;
  -webkit-column-rule: 2px solid #999;
  column-rule: 2px solid #999;
}

#container div {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
  <div class="item">19</div>
  <div class="item">20</div>
  <div class="item">21</div>
</div>
```

And, of course, adjust the gutters between the columns, using `column-gap`:

```css
#container {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -ms-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  -moz-column-rule: 2px solid #999;
  -ms-column-rule: 2px solid #999;
  -webkit-column-rule: 2px solid #999;
  column-rule: 2px solid #999;
  -moz-column-gap: 3em;
  -ms-column-gap: 3em;
  -webkit-column-gap: 3em;
  column-gap: 3em;
}
#container div {
  background-color: #fff;
}
#container div:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
  <div class="item">11</div>
  <div class="item">12</div>
  <div class="item">13</div>
  <div class="item">14</div>
  <div class="item">15</div>
  <div class="item">16</div>
  <div class="item">17</div>
  <div class="item">18</div>
  <div class="item">19</div>
  <div class="item">20</div>
  <div class="item">21</div>
</div>
```

References:

- [`column-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-count).
- [`column-gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap).
- [`column-rule`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/column-rule).

Comment: thank you! elegant and simple solution! didnt know this

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have helped! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `display:inline-block` on all of the divs like so.

```css
.champion-wrapper{
  width:150px;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="champion-wrapper">1</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">2</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">3</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">4</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">5</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">6</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">7</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">8</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">9</div>
<div class="champion-wrapper">10</div>
```

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP already gets this layout (it's shown in the first ASCII picture, and is the "*layout [s/he] wants to rearrange*" in the image shown); the desired layout is columnar (shown in the second ASCII picture).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `columns` [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/vdudtjhy/1/)

```
#champions { 
  -webkit-columns: 3;
  -moz-columns: 3;
  columns: 3;
}
```